# Why does scaling down service meshed pod using Linkerd not reflect in Eureka-server quickly?

Tags: netflix-eureka, linkerd

scaling down service meshed pod does not reflect in Eureka-server.
i have a set of spring boot services which are deployed in a local kubernetes cluster, one eureka server (for discovery part), and two backend services ( eureka clients ), when i deploy them in local kubernetes and when i scale down or up one of my backend services, changes are begin reflected quickly in eureka server, but when i use Linkerd and use **linkerd.io/inject: enabled** in deployment files, something unusual occur, by scaling up backend services there is no problem and eureka server detect this change very quickly, but when i scale down changes are not being reflected in eureka server quickly and it tooks about 3 to 5 minutes.
this is eureka client configuration for one of my backend services:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8769/eureka
```

and this is eureka-server configuration i'm using

```
server:
  port: 8769
spring:
  application:
    name: discovery-server
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost1
    prefer-ip-address: true
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 60
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 30
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
```

does anyone had the same issue ?